# Fatal exception-main error Welcome login acess

Tags: android, json

This is my LogCat

```
12-26 15:21:46.894: E/Trace(870): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-26 15:21:47.934: D/gralloc_goldfish(870): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
12-26 15:21:56.574: D/dalvikvm(870): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 202K, 9% free 7439K/8135K, paused 36ms, total 40ms
12-26 15:21:58.554: D/dalvikvm(870): GC_CONCURRENT freed 229K, 10% free 7629K/8455K, paused 26ms+176ms, total 286ms
12-26 15:21:59.095: D/Create Response(870): {"message":"Login successfully.","success":1}
12-26 15:21:59.875: I/Choreographer(870): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-26 15:22:01.005: D/Create Response(870): {"3":"jmi.mohsin@gmail.com","2":"myname","1":"msnmsn","0":"8527801400","mobile_number":"8527801400","hint":"myname","email_id":"jmi.mohsin@gmail.com","password":"msnmsn"}
12-26 15:22:01.065: D/AndroidRuntime(870): Shutting down VM
12-26 15:22:01.065: W/dalvikvm(870): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.example.phonebook.Welcome$loginAccess.onPostExecute(Welcome.java:92)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.example.phonebook.Welcome$loginAccess.onPostExecute(Welcome.java:1)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-26 15:22:01.085: E/AndroidRuntime(870):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**my Activity is**

```
public class Welcome extends Activity {
//  private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    int flag=0;
    TextView jsonParsed1,DataShow;  
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ///private static String url ="http://192.168.1.10/android_connect/login_setup/show_data.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork()
        .penaltyLog().build());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);       
        jsonParsed1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.jsonParsed);
        DataShow=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.show_all_data);        
        String abt = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile_number");
        jsonParsed1.setText(abt);       
        new loginAccess().execute();
    }
class loginAccess extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {   
        String abt = getIntent().getStringExtra("mobile_number");       
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile_number", abt));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"POST", params);       
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
        String ShowData = json.toString();
        System.out.print(ShowData);     
        return ShowData;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String ShowData) {     
           /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/    
        String OutputData = "";
        JSONObject jsonResponse;              try {
/****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
             jsonResponse = new JSONObject(ShowData.toString());              
             /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
             /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
             JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Android");              
             /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/               
                 /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                 JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(0);                  
                 /******* Fetch node values **********/
                 String hint       = jsonChildNode.optString("hint").toString();
                 OutputData +="Full Detail \n\n"+ hint
                    +"--------------------------------------------------\n";
                 DataShow.setText( OutputData );
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();        }    }
```

Comment: Why is it tagged Java, PHP, json and eclipse? And, did you read the error? `java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.phonebook.Welcome$loginAccess.onPostExecute(Welcome.java:92)`

Comment: Just look at line 92. And maybe stop using block comments within your code

Comment: _You_ should look at it.

Comment: Then `jsonMainNode` is null, or `getJSONObject(0)` returns null. You need to learn how to read the logcat, and debug your program.

Comment: what is there solution where to the return null.. but log cat show the Json response

Comment: "there is my logcat and my activity"... you could put some effort in explaining your problem if you expect someone to take you serious

Answer (score 0):

The `jsonMainNode` is always null because your json does not contains any key with the `Android` tag.

```
{
    "3": "jmi.mohsin@gmail.com",
    "2": "myname",
    "1": "msnmsn",
    "0": "8527801400",
    "mobile_number": "8527801400",
    "hint": "myname",
    "email_id": "jmi.mohsin@gmail.com",
    "password": "msnmsn"
}
```

You should call directly `jsonResponse.optString("hint").toString();`